# Why does my visual studio 2008 often freeze?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2008 it often freeze when Im coding..
I go to event viewer and found this error:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3625 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A2F89BA) (0)
```

Last week my IDE work's fine ..but now it fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These types of issues are often really really vague and difficult to troubleshoot.

I would suggest checking out to see if [perfwatson](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441) helps. Install a [companion component](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3c888f2-40e0-4370-83e0-2952febf9e4f) to help monitor VS's performance visually. This is essentially a tool designed to monitor and figure out why Visual Studio freezes or crashes with the intent on providing the feedback to Microsoft. While that may not be immediately useful to you, with the visualizer it may help to identify where and when things start to going wrong.

You may even want to try [forcing a manual garbage collection in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2010/12/15/force-vs-to-garbage-collect.aspx) from time to time to see if its possibly memory related.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall .net and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Don't think this will solve the issue. Google the error he posted and many complain that reinstalling .net did not work.